# Adding ActionListeners to a new JButton created in a loop

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to add an `ActionListener` to a `JButton` created in a loop, then call the `ActionListener` from another class (the controller class), but it's not working. Here is the first class:

```
private void configurePanel() {
    increment = 0;
    while (increment < file_location.size() && increment < file_imglocation.size()) {
        configureButtonPanel(increment, file_location, file_imglocation);
        increment++;
    }
}

private void configureButtonPanel(int increment, ArrayList<String> file_location, ArrayList<String> file_imglocation) {
    File f = new File(file_location.get(increment));
    int video_no = increment;
    String str = video_no + 1 + " " + f.getName();
    str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
    btn_control_pnl = new JPanel();
    btn_control_pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    //jbutton created in a loop
    btn_control_pnl.add(createButton(increment, file_imglocation.get(increment), str));
    btn_control_pnl.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    main_pnl.add(btn_control_pnl);
}

private JButton createButton(final int i, String img_loc, String file_name) {
    File f = new File(img_loc);
    play_lists_btn = new JButton();
    play_lists_btn.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    play_lists_btn.setText(file_name);
    play_lists_btn.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
    play_lists_btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    String fname = "Images\\" + f.getName();

    return play_lists_btn;
}

public void addPlayListener(ActionListener play) {
    play_lists_btn.addActionListener( play);
}
```

Here is the controller class that calls the button action listener, and creates an action event for the button:

```
public class BrowseMediaPlayerListsControlListener {

    private BrowseMediaPlayerListsPanel browse_video_pnl;

    public BrowseMediaPlayerListsControlListener(BrowseMediaPlayerListsPanel browse_video_pnl) {
        this.browse_video_pnl = browse_video_pnl;
        this.browse_video_pnl.addPlayListener(new PlayListener());
    }

    private class PlayListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("play is: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work, the print statement never show up.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough code here to detect the problem. For example, where do you create a `new BrowseMediaPlayerListsControlListener()`? (Actually, that could be your problem)

Comment: where are you calling thr addPlayListener() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding action listeners to a new jbutton created in a loop in java and called from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971114/adding-action-listeners-to-a-new-jbutton-created-in-a-loop-in-java-and-called-fr)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you never create a new `BrowseMediaPlayerListsControlListener()`, and the constructor of that method is what calls `addPlayListener()`.

You will get your desired functionality if you add this line to `createButton`:

```
play_lists_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println("play is: ");
   }
} );
```

Comment: i get what you mean @david, but i want to be able to access the button listener from another class, which is the BrowseMediaPlayerListsControlListener() class. I am trying to follow the MVC pattern. i dont know if it could be possible.